# How do I get the number of points a user earned on a Foursquare Checkin?

Tags: foursquare

I looked at the Foursquare API docs, but I couldn't find a way for Foursquare to tell me how many points a user earned for a specific checkin.

Answer (score 3):

The [`checkin`](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin) response has a field `score` that is not (yet) mentioned in the documentation:

```
  "score":  {
    "scores":  [
       {
        "points": 3,
        "icon": "https://foursquare.com/img/points/discovery-venue3.png",
        "message": "First time at Frauenkirche"
      },
       {
        "points": 2,
        "icon": "https://foursquare.com/img/points/discovery.png",
        "message": "First among friends to check in at Frauenkirche"
      }
    ],
    "total": 5
  }
```

Comment: This stopped working for me when I moved to a newer API version (this month)